# namespace locked for RQuantLib

Tags: r, quantlib

Running this on RStudio/Windows. The last line fails with:

> Error in registerNames(names, package, ".**global**", add) :    The
>   namespace for package "RQuantLib" is locked; no changes in the global
>   variables list may be made.

```
library(RQuantLib)

myStrike <- 1240
myPrice <- 1410

volVec <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5)
priceVec <- c(1500,1400,1300,1200,1100)
myType <- "put"
rfRate <- 0.02
maturity <- 360/360
vol <- 0.3


EO = EuropeanOption(type = myType,price = myPrice,strike = myStrike, dividendYield = 0,riskFreeRate = rfRate, maturity = maturity,volatility = vol )
EOres = EuropeanOptionArrays(type = myType,price = priceVec,strike = myStrike, dividendYield = 0,riskFreeRate = rfRate, maturity = maturity,volatility = volVec )
summary(EO)
plotOptionSurface(EOres)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for asking this question, and apologies for missing it for a few days.  An issue ticket at GitHub would have been ok too.

The code you post (and possibly quoted from old documentation of mine...) is buggy.  The second argument to both `EuropeanOption()` and `EuropeanOptionArrays()` is now `underlying`, not `price`.  So we make this

```
library(RQuantLib)

myStrike <- 1240
myPrice <- 1410

volVec <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5)
priceVec <- c(1500,1400,1300,1200,1100)
myType <- "put"
rfRate <- 0.02
maturity <- 360/360
vol <- 0.3


EO <- EuropeanOption(type = myType, underlying = myPrice,strike = myStrike,
                     dividendYield = 0, riskFreeRate = rfRate, maturity = maturity,
                     volatility = vol )
EOres <- EuropeanOptionArrays(type = myType, underlying = priceVec,strike = myStrike, 
                              dividendYield = 0,riskFreeRate = rfRate, maturity = maturity,
                              volatility = volVec )
summary(EO)
plotOptionSurface(EOres)
```

Next, in the function `plotOptionSurface()` we need to comment out the call to `globalVariables()`, this can no longer be in a function body. So make it eg

```
pos <- function(EOres, ylabel="", xlabel="", zlabel="", fov=60) {
    if (requireNamespace("rgl", quietly=TRUE)) {
        #utils::globalVariables(c("clear3d", "bg3d", "ligh3d", "rgl.viewpoint", "rgl.surface", "tgl.texts"))
        axis.col <- "black"
        text.col <- axis.col
        ylab <- ylabel
        xlab <- xlabel
        zlab <- zlabel
        y <- EOres

        ## clear scene:
        rgl::clear3d()
        rgl::clear3d(type="bbox")
        rgl::clear3d(type="lights")

        ## setup env:
        rgl::bg3d(color="#DDDDDD")
        rgl::light3d()

        rgl::rgl.viewpoint(fov=fov)

        x <- 1:nrow(y)
        z <- 1:ncol(y)
        x <- (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))
        y <- (y-min(y))/(max(y)-min(y))
        z <- (z-min(z))/(max(z)-min(z))
        rgl::rgl.surface(x, z, y, alpha=0.6, lit=TRUE, color="blue")
        rgl::rgl.lines(c(0,1), c(0,0), c(0,0), col=axis.col)
        rgl::rgl.lines(c(0,0), c(0,1), c(0,0), col=axis.col)
        rgl::rgl.lines(c(0,0),c(0,0), c(0,1), col=axis.col)
        rgl::rgl.texts(1,0,0, xlab, adj=1, col=text.col)
        rgl::rgl.texts(0,1,0, ylab, adj=1, col=text.col)
        rgl::rgl.texts(0,0,1, zlab, adj=1, col=text.col)

        ## add grid (credit's to John Fox scatter3d)
        xgridind <- round(seq(1, nrow(y), length=25))
        zgridind <- round(seq(1, ncol(y), length=25))
        rgl::rgl.surface(x[xgridind], z[zgridind], y[xgridind,zgridind],
                         color="darkgray", alpha=0.5, lit=TRUE,
                         front="lines", back="lines")

        ## animate (credit to rgl.viewpoint() example)
        start <- proc.time()[3]
        while ((i <- 36*(proc.time()[3]-start)) < 360) {
            rgl::rgl.viewpoint(i,i/8);
        }
    } else {
        message("Please install the 'rgl' package before using this function.")
    }
}
```

Now we can call with element of the result list, eg

```
pos(EOres[[1]])  # value
```

and ditto for the others.

Comment: Thanks! Do you generally recommend definig a new function rather than overwriting?

Comment: No that was just for the example. More importantly it's a bug that I will fix.  Where did you see the outdated example though?

Comment: I made it, my fault with price rather than underlying.

Comment: Yes, your call was wrong, but the bug to fix is the `utils::globalVariables()` call which needs to move outside the function -- this lead to the error in your Subject:. Error on my side, and I will fix it.